# Subclasses of simple functions dense in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Q1. Consider $f\in L^2([0,1], R)$ with $ ||f||^2=\int f(x)^2d\mu(x)$

Consdier a subclass of simple functions   $f= \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \chi_{A_i}$ where $A_i\in \Sigma$ (on $[0,1]$) and $A_n\subseteq...\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_1$,

Is the subclass dense  in $L^2([0,1], R)$?

Q2. Consider $f\in L^2([0,1], R^2)$ with $ ||f||^2=\int \langle f(x),f(x) \rangle^2 d\mu(x)$

If the class of simple functions   $f=(f_1,f_2)=( \sum_{i=1}^m a_i \chi_{A_i}, \sum_{j=1}^n b_j \chi_{B_j})$ is dense, i.e. for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $f\in L^2([0,1], R^2)$ such that $||f-f^*||<\epsilon$, for all $f^*\in L^2([0,1], R^2)$.

Could I further make such $f$ satisfying $m=n$ and $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$?

Thanks.

Comment: You should convince yourself that the "subclass" you describe is just the class of all simple functions and hence dense in $L^2$.

Comment: Hi,  you mean it holds also for Q2?

Comment: Yes, for Q2, for getting $a_i = b_i$, you can just set $A_i = \emptyset$ or $B_i = \emptyset$ for some values of $i$. Thus, getting $m=n$ is also no problem.